# How to resize grid-view column width?

Tags: css, gridview, webforms

I am trying to re-size columns width in my gridview that I created using [this tutorial](http://www.ashishblog.com/blog/nested-gridview-in-showhide-effect-using-c-net/), but I am unable to do so. I have been through tens of ways by googling but non of them worked.

Code that is creating problem

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" HtmlEncode="False" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" HtmlEncode="False" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" HtmlEncode="False" />
<asp:TemplateField> // I don't want to show it in my gridview as it is just being
                    // for showing nested gridview
<ItemTemplate>
</td></tr>
```

I tried to change column visiblity but then show/hide button doesn't work anymore.

This is how my gridview looks like,

[image]

I want to hide last empty column or minimize it's width so it should be hidden and increase description column width, decrease ID number column width and also first column's width,

I even tried CSS way but then it says width 0px however no change in width and `ControlStyle-Width="10%"` but it didn't worked.

Comment: can you please show code in details for gridview??

Comment: Can you read the post properly please ? Link is there with all code you need :)

Comment: set HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign, ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign property of each gridview bound field.

Comment: why each ? can't I just add it to one I need to change size of ? thanks

Comment: I am not sure if changing Align will be any good ?

Comment: its better to add your gridview in the column of adresss or last column of ur grid view.

Comment: Have a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms178296(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: didn't worked @RohanLeuva

Comment: post the code you have modified using that link

Comment: I tried this but it's not working, isn't that enough ? GridView1.Columns[2].ItemStyle.Width

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dear friend use the following code

```
    <asp:GridView runat="server" id="testGrid">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" HtmlEncode="False" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" HtmlEncode="False" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" HtmlEncode="False" ItemStyle-Width="100px" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

or if you understand the css then use the following code in which you have to assign the css class to ControlStyle-CssClass property

```
    <asp:GridView runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" HtmlEncode="False" ControlStyle-CssClass="cssclass1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" HtmlEncode="False" ControlStyle-CssClass="cssclass2"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" HtmlEncode="False" ControlStyle-CssClass="cssclass3" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can resize columns specifying `ItemStyle-Width` property for gridview columns.

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" ItemStyle-Width="200px" 
 InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductID" >
 </asp:BoundField>
```

The template field column will be visible for blank values. However, you can work around this by either disabling column borders through css or letting the column render as a new table row like this in your aspx code

```
<asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="100%">
            <!-- your nested control goes here-->
        </td>
    </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```